# dplyr group_by multiple function arguments via Non Standard Evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval, quosure

I was reading [dplyr's vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) trying to figure out how to use `dplyr` in my function codes. Mid way through it talks about how to use `enquos` on `...` in order to pass multiple arguments to group_by.

a short example of how it would work

```
grp <- rlang::enquos(...)
df %>%
    group_by(!!!grp)
```

I didn't know if there was a way to assign multiple expression values without reserving `...` without doing some questionable coding.

To get an idea of what the call would look like use the following example:

```
#reproducable data
df <- datasets::USJudgeRatings
df$name <- rownames(df)
df <- tidyr::gather(df, key = "key", value = "value", -name)
df$dummy <- c("1","2")


test_summarize <- function(df, sum.col, grp = NULL, filter = NULL) {
  filter <- rlang::enquo(filter)
  sum.col <- rlang::enquo(sum.col)
  if(!is.null(rlang::get_expr(filter))){
    df <- dplyr::filter(df, !!filter)
  }

  #how grp is turned into a character vector to be passed to .dots in group_by
  grp <- substitute(grp)
  if(!is.null(grp)){
    grp <- deparse(grp)
    grp <- strsplit(gsub(pattern = "list\\(|c\\(|\\)|", replacement = "", x = grp), split =",")[[1]]
    grp <- gsub(pattern = "^ | $", replacement = "", x = grp)
   df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(.dots=grp) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(!!sum.col), sum = sum(!!sum.col), n = n())
  } else{
    df %>%
      dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(!!sum.col), sum = sum(!!sum.col), n = n())
  }

}

test_summarize(df, sum.col=value, grp = c(name, dummy))

# A tibble: 86 x 5
# Groups:   name [?]
   name           dummy  mean   sum     n
   <chr>          <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 AARONSON,L.H.  1      7.17  43       6
 2 AARONSON,L.H.  2      7.42  44.5     6
 3 ALEXANDER,J.M. 1      8.35  50.1     6
 4 ALEXANDER,J.M. 2      7.95  47.7     6
 5 ARMENTANO,A.J. 1      7.53  45.2     6
 6 ARMENTANO,A.J. 2      7.7   46.2     6
 7 BERDON,R.I.    1      8.67  52       6
 8 BERDON,R.I.    2      8.25  49.5     6
 9 BRACKEN,J.J.   1      5.65  33.9     6
10 BRACKEN,J.J.   2      5.82  34.9     6
# ... with 76 more rows
```

This works for what I was trying to do, but I was wondering if there was a better way to accept the arguments and handle them. Every attempt I made in turning the original `grp` call into something that resembles what `enquos(...)` failed so I did a deparsing and turned them into a character vector, which honestly I should probably just expect the user to pass characters?

I am opting to not use a character vector as the expected input because I was trying to remain consistent considering that sum.col and filter arguments of the function expect NSE expressions. Maybe there is something in the rlang package that will convert each element of the original expression into a list of quosures?

*Edit: fixed reproducible example and provided expected output*

Comment: @RonakShah, fixed the error, left out the line where I converted the row names to a column vector

Comment: You can use `{{}}` for the unquoted variables and it may better to pass a quoted vector and make use of `group_by_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use `group_by_at`, we may not need the `if/else` argument

```
test_summarize <- function(df, sum.col, grp = NULL, filter = NULL) {
df %>% 
     group_by_at(grp) %>%
     summarise(mean = mean({{sum.col}}), 
               sum = sum({{sum.col}}), n = n())

   }


test_summarize(df, sum.col=value, grp = c("name", "dummy"))
# A tibble: 86 x 5
# Groups:   name [43]
#   name           dummy  mean   sum     n
#   <chr>          <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 AARONSON,L.H.  1      7.17  43       6
# 2 AARONSON,L.H.  2      7.42  44.5     6
# 3 ALEXANDER,J.M. 1      8.35  50.1     6
# 4 ALEXANDER,J.M. 2      7.95  47.7     6
# 5 ARMENTANO,A.J. 1      7.53  45.2     6
# 6 ARMENTANO,A.J. 2      7.7   46.2     6
# 7 BERDON,R.I.    1      8.67  52       6
# 8 BERDON,R.I.    2      8.25  49.5     6
# 9 BRACKEN,J.J.   1      5.65  33.9     6
#10 BRACKEN,J.J.   2      5.82  34.9     6
# … with 76 more rows



test_summarize(df, sum.col=value)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   mean   sum     n
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1  7.57 3908.   516
```

which is the same as

```
df %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(value), sum = sum(value), n = n())
#     mean    sum   n
#1 7.57345 3907.9 516
```

---

If we  use `filter`, then one option is `...` and pass as many filter conditions

```
test_summarize <- function(df, sum.col, grp = NULL, ...) {
    df %>% 
         filter(!!! rlang::enexprs(...)) %>%
         group_by_at(grp) %>%
         summarise(mean = mean({{sum.col}}), sum = sum({{sum.col}}), n = n())

}


test_summarize(df, sum.col=value, grp = c("name", "dummy"),
        key %in% c("CONT", "INTG"), value > 6.5)
# A tibble: 77 x 5
# Groups:   name [43]
#   name           dummy  mean   sum     n
#   <chr>          <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 AARONSON,L.H.  2       7.9   7.9     1
# 2 ALEXANDER,J.M. 1       8.9   8.9     1
# 3 ALEXANDER,J.M. 2       6.8   6.8     1
# 4 ARMENTANO,A.J. 1       7.2   7.2     1
# 5 ARMENTANO,A.J. 2       8.1   8.1     1
# 6 BERDON,R.I.    1       8.8   8.8     1
# 7 BERDON,R.I.    2       6.8   6.8     1
# 8 BRACKEN,J.J.   1       7.3   7.3     1
# 9 BURNS,E.B.     1       8.8   8.8     1
#10 CALLAHAN,R.J.  1      10.6  10.6     1
# … with 67 more rows
```

and this will also evaluate when there are no filter arguments

```
test_summarize(df, sum.col=value, grp = c("name", "dummy"))
# A tibble: 86 x 5
# Groups:   name [43]
#   name           dummy  mean   sum     n
#   <chr>          <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 AARONSON,L.H.  1      7.17  43       6
# 2 AARONSON,L.H.  2      7.42  44.5     6
# 3 ALEXANDER,J.M. 1      8.35  50.1     6
# 4 ALEXANDER,J.M. 2      7.95  47.7     6
# 5 ARMENTANO,A.J. 1      7.53  45.2     6
# 6 ARMENTANO,A.J. 2      7.7   46.2     6
# 7 BERDON,R.I.    1      8.67  52       6
# 8 BERDON,R.I.    2      8.25  49.5     6
# 9 BRACKEN,J.J.   1      5.65  33.9     6
#10 BRACKEN,J.J.   2      5.82  34.9     6
# … with 76 more rows
```

which is the same as thee first output

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I suppose using a character vector is actually the most concise way to expect grouping columns.

Comment: @JustinLandis  Can you show your `filter` expressions how you are passing

Comment: filter expressions are to be written how you would in the `subset` function. The assignment may look something like this `filter = key%in%c("CONT", "INTG")&value>6.5`

Comment: definitely a more concise version - Thanks!